# Controller action is called twice when query string ends with a dot

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In an old MVC application I have this (plain HTTPGET) controller action that accepts a query string parameter and does a redirect based on it. It always redirects to another action, however when the query string ends with a `.`, the action is run twice. First it is run with the correct parameter and the second time with the same parameter, but without the dot. The user eventually gets the result from the second (incorrect) run and the redirect from the first run is ignored.

When the query string doesn't end with a dot, everything is fine and the action is called only once.

Does anybody have any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of desperation I looked into Global.asax with the intention of debugging a request step by step. To my surprise I found `Application_PreSendRequestHeaders` method there that did the redirect. I totally don't know why I haven't looked there earlier. I'm sure I asked around when I stumbled upon this problem, but this redirect was written so long ago by a colleague of mine, that he didn't even remember writing it there in the first place.

It's certainly a weird way to do a redirect (it was messing with the header) and as a side effect it was calling the action twice.

Comment: The answer turned out to be a bit anticlimactic, but I'm sure glad the issue is over now.

Answer (score 0):

Set this in your Web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Comment: I have this in my web,config, but the problem is it doesn't work. What's even more strange is that I have another nearly identical app running and it doesn't have this error.